# Java reflection: casting Integer coming from a class's field

Tags: java, casting, reflect

I have recently run into the following error which really confuses me. I have imported reflect. I have a class (called worker) with a field which is a private int called numOfJobs. In the constructor of Worker, numOfJobs is set to 0. Then, in a tester class, I create an instance of type worker:

```
    waterBenders[0] = new Worker();
    Field []fields = waterBenders[0].getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    Field privateFieldJobs = fields[0];
    privateFieldJobs.setAccessible(true);

    try{

          System.out.println(privateFieldJobs.get(waterBenders[0]));

          System.out.println(privateFieldJobs.get(waterBenders[0]).getClass());

          System.out.println((int)privateFieldJobs.get(waterBenders[0]));
    }
```

It is the third line in the try box which is contains the error.
The first two lines print:

```
    0    
    class java.lang.Integer
```

This makes sense to me. However, if the object privateFieldJobs.get(waterBenders[0]) is an object of type Integer with "value" 0, then why should (int)privateFieldJobs.get(waterBenders[0]) throw the error:

```
    Cannot cast from java.lang.Object to int
```

If I was to create a normal object of type Integer, then this type of casting usually works. What is so special about this example? I imagine it has something to do with the fact that this Integer object is coming from the fields array.

My worker class is essentially:

```
    public class Worker extends Unit{
      private int numOfJobs;

      public Worker(Tile position, double hp, String faction) {
        super(position, hp, 2, faction);   
        this.numOfJobs = 0;
      }

      public int getNumOfJobs(){
        return this.numOfJobs;
      }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the definition of the `Worker` class?

Answer (score 3):

It is because Field#get returns an Object, and you can not cast any Object type to a primitive type in java. If you want the primitive integer value from an Integer object, you can do something like this

```
Integer field = (Integer) privateFieldJobs.get(waterBenders[0]);
int value = field.intValue();
```

Comment: You can simply do `int field = (Integer) privateFieldJobs.get(waterBenders[0]);`.

Comment: No you would need to do `int field = ((Integer) privateFieldJobs.get(waterBenders[0])).intValue();`

Comment: Yes, I just did it like that so it was simpler to read for him

Comment: @KyleAure you don’t need to call `intValue()` manually when assigning an `Integer` to an `int`, since Java 5, that is since fifteen years now.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you are attempting this:

```
Integer i=1;
Object o=i;
int val=(int)o;
```

It has no reason to work, that is why it does not.

Either cast it back to `Integer` (as you see, it is not necessary for a `println`, as the correct `toString()` gets invoked anyway, but it is required for unboxing), or you can try using [`getInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getInt(java.lang.Object)):

```
int val1=(Integer)privateFieldJobs.get(waterBenders[0]);
int val2=privateFieldJobs.getInt(waterBenders[0]);
```

---

Well, I was wrong about the latter: while both of them work for an `int`, but `getInt()` does not work on an `Integer`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Ideone {
    public Integer objInt=23;
    public int valInt=42;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Field objField=Ideone.class.getField("objInt");
        Field valField=Ideone.class.getField("valInt");

        Ideone test=new Ideone();

        System.out.print("objInt-get: ");
        System.out.println(objField.get(test));

        System.out.print("objInt-getInt: ");
        try{
            System.out.println(objField.getInt(test));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getClass());
        }

        System.out.print("valInt-get: ");
        System.out.println(valField.get(test));

        System.out.print("valInt-getInt: ");
        System.out.println(valField.getInt(test));
    }
}
```

(class is called `Ideone`, because it can be tried there: https://ideone.com/91xzmc)
Output:

> ```
> objInt-get: 23
> objInt-getInt: class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
> valInt-get: 42
> valInt-getInt: 42
> ```

So one can use both `get()` and `getInt()` on an `int` field, but when the field is `Integer`, only get works. (The `ex.getClass()` magic is just about shortening the message, by default there is a long explanation which does not fit in a line).

Side note: usage of number classes, like `Integer`, means creating objects, on the heap (which can add to heap fragmentation, and can make extra work for the garbage collector). If you do not specifically need a number to be `null`-able, or to be an object for any other reason (some exotic serializers may need that), use `int`. It is faster, lighter and even shorter to type, plus needs no touch of <kbd>Shift</kbd> (for `I`).